# Converting a Curl command to run in a Zapier Webhook

Tags: curl, webhooks, zapier

I'm trying to find a way to run this `curl` command in the Webhook Zap on Zapier, but I can't seem to figure it out. How would I enter this in the Webhook? Would it be better to run it as a `Code` Zap?

```
curl -X POST "https://api.zoom.us/v2/users?access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJmY3FvTHlyRVRpR3VmWmw2dW1ZU2NBIiwiaWF0IjoxNTI4Njc0OTUxLCJleHAiOjE1Mjg2OTI5NTF9.fvDzS8-UtHyO_YUF5-eqLyuopAuoL48SRwKxcOV1YrE" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"action\": \"create\", \"user_info\": { \"email\": \"test@test.com\", \"type\": 1, \"first_name\": \"Chris\", \"last_name\": \"G\", \"password\": \"Test54321\" }}"
```

Answer (score 9):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Luckily, this is an easy one. Since you're using nested data, you'll need to use Webhooks by Zapier's **Custom Request**. The setup is the following:

Body & URL:
[image]

Headers:
[image]

You can also do it through code, you'll have the same result.

Also, if that `access_token` is still live, make sure to revoke it now that it's been out in the public!